# probability question on test papers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[image]

For the first part i get 5^3 and for the second part would it be (5+2-1c2) and how would i answer part 3?

Answer (score 3):

Your answer to part (a) is incorrect, because the number of options is 3, and the number of questions is 5.  Your calculation counts a situation for which the number of options is 5, and the number of questions is 3.

Part (b) is also incorrect.  You can count the desired possibilities by counting the complement:  i.e., how many possibilities do not have *any* "A" answers?  How many possibilities have *exactly one* "A" answer?

In part (c), try using a "slot" approach.  Think of each of the five questions as a slot, and for each slot, enumerate the total number of ways you can fill that slot:  so for example, the first question (slot) can be filled in 3 ways.  Given that the first slot was filled with some value, how many ways could you choose to fill in the second slot; i.e., choose an answer for the second question?  This would be 2 ways, since you cannot choose the same answer choice as you chose in the first question.  Continue this reasoning.